# Checkbox Input is returning Boolean values when placed in view model AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have the following HTML markup:

```
        <div class="blog-admin-article-sidebar-item-content">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input ng-model="vm.newArticle.category" type="checkbox" value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input ng-model="vm.newArticle.category" type="checkbox" value="SEAT">SEAT</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input ng-model="vm.newArticle.category" type="checkbox" value="SKODA">SKODA</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input ng-model="vm.newArticle.category" type="checkbox" value="Pulman Group">Pulman Group</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see my input check-box's have custom values such as `Volkswagen` for example.

For some reason I seem to be having an issue with selecting the check-box's and placing the value within my `view model`.

Here is an example of my controller:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.admin')
    .controller('AdminController', AdminController);

    AdminController.$inject = ['$firebaseArray'];

    function AdminController($firebaseArray) {
      var vm = this;

      var fireArticles = new Firebase('XXX');

      function Article() {
        this.name = '';
        this.content = '';
        this.category = '';
        this.published = false;
      }

      vm.newArticle = new Article();
      vm.articles = $firebaseArray(fireArticles);
      vm.addArticle = addArticle;

      function addArticle() {
        vm.articles.$add(vm.newArticle);
      }
    }
})();
```

As you see I am declaring my View Model named as `vm`.

I'm quite confused why the checkbox value is being placed within my vm.newArticle.category as a Boolean value and not the value that is assigned to the checkbox?

My view model is currently outputting:

```
"category":true
```

Any help with this would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to bind some value upon checking and unchecking the checkbox use 
`ng-true-value="someValue"` and `ng-false-value="someValue"`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your use case, a checkbox seems to be the wrong control because article.category can only ever have one value and a checkbox would allow multiple selections.  In this case, I would recommend using radio buttons [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/umpuvPefHMvY5eoetJH6)

However, if you did want to support multiple categories being selected at the same time I would recommend this approach.

```
function Article() {
  this.name = '';
  this.content = '';
  this.category = {
    skoda: false,
    seat: false,
    Volkswagen: false
  }
}
```

An html:
    
`<input ng-model="vm.newArticle.category.skoda"type="checkbox">SKODA</label>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "select" control instead of checkbox.

for example:

```
<select ng-model="vm.newArticle.category" required>
     <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
     <option value="SEAT">SEAT</option>
     <option value="SKODA">SKODA</option>
</select>
```

and you will have your "category" populated as string in your object.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using boolean variable to bind the checkbox please refer the below example:

```
  <div ng-repeat="book in books">
  <input type="checkbox"   ng-model="book.selected"  ng-
  click="function(sample)">
  </div>
```